# Converting bootstrap navbar and contents as rtl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to convert the following navbar direction and behavior of submenus to the other direction..

This is the original code, and below it is the edited one that needs more tweaking to be "right to left":

**The original:**

```js
// dropdown menu on hover 
var $screensize = $(window).width();
$('.dropdown').on("mouseover", function() {

  $(this).find('> .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
  $(this).bind('mouseleave', function() {

    $(this).find('> .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).css('display', 'none');
  });
});

//Change position for drop down
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown li").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if ($('.dropdown-menu', this).length) {
      var elm = $('.dropdown-menu', this);
      var off = elm.offset();
      var l = off.left;
      var w = elm.width();
      var docW = $(window).width();

      var isEntirelyVisible = (l + w <= docW);

      if (!isEntirelyVisible) {
        $(elm).addClass('dropdown-reverse');
      } else {
        $(elm).removeClass('dropdown-reverse');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -2px;
}

li.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.dropdown-reverse {
  left: auto!important;
  right: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Action</a><ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Action</a><ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I edited the above and added `.navbar{float: right;  }` in the css, `text-align:right` for `li dropdown` and also `dir="rtl"` in the top line of `nav` in the html.  But still the behavior is not as intended, as the `rtl` css addition made it lose the respect for the screen size as this image (this is the original):
[image]

But now it only opens one first two right, but the third submenu gets opened over the first one.

Here is a fiddle for the test: https://jsfiddle.net/2b8h30Lx/41/

Comment: *«But still the behavior is not as intended»* is unclear.

Comment: `li.dropdown, li.dropdown * {text-align:right;}` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. the `text-align:right` worked for the submenus, but not the main menu.  I added a picture also for what the behaviour should be.

Comment: The space on the right of the top bar? Try `.navbar-nav{padding:0;}`

Comment: I'm not sure... but have a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/kqvbfngy/)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Now there is only one issue: to make the child menu respect the screen size like the ltr version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UMCo.jpg  Anu suggestions?